# JUnit test for RestController with JDBCTemplate in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, junit

My Controller is something like below :

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@RequestMapping(value="/1",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<List<Map<String, Object>>> abc(@RequestBody String[] arr) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> result =jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from Table_Name where  COL1='"+arr[1]+"' and  COL2='"+arr[2]+"' order by COL3");
    
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Map<String,Object>>>(result,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I wrote the test class as below :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MainClass.class)
@WebAppConfiguration

public class TestWebApplication {
    protected MockMvc mvc;
       @Autowired
       WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

       protected void setUp() {
          mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
       }

    @Test
    public void testabc() throws Exception{
         mvc.perform(post("/1").andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")));
      
    }
```

Getting error at andExpect, asking to cast that method.

Please anyone help me out in writing Junit test case for JDBC template.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the test class to below :

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MainClass.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TestWebApplication {
    
     @Autowired
      private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
      private MockMvc mockMvc;

      @Before
      public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
      }

    @Test
    public void testabc() throws Exception{
        String[] arr ={"A","B"};
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false);
        ObjectWriter ow = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        String requestJson=ow.writeValueAsString(arr );
        mockMvc.perform( post("/1").contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(requestJson));
    
    }
```